# How to correctly include a PHP header on every page

Tags: php, templates, header, include

My current project routes everything through index.php. Then I see what the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is, check against a whitelist, then perform some logic to include the relevant html template. Like this:

```
<?php

include("header.html");

$requested_page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ($requested_page in $whitelist){
    $page_title = $requested_page;
    include ($requested_page . "_controller.php");
    include ($requested_page . "_template.html");
}

include ("footer.html")

?>
```

My problem is that I want to use `$page_title` in the header template, like this...

`<title><?php echo $page_title?></title>`

But obviously it will not work because when the header is included, $page_title has not been set. Can anyone suggest how to get around this? Might "output buffering" help? If so, how?
If there is something majorly wrong with this way of using php to produce pages, please say so ! Thanks

EDIT: I should add, the conditional logic is quite a bit more complicated in my real project,  and I've simplified it a lot here. I don't want to have to keep repeating my includes of header and footer, so that's why they're not included. I'd really rather keep them out of all the logic if possible.

Comment: Why not include header after you check what's the requested page ?

Comment: Regarding your edit. There's not really a clean way to change the title once header.html has been include. Short of parsing the output buffers.

Comment: @Jim Maybe that's something I need to do. But I don't really know what "parsing the output buffers" means. It would be good for the PHP to get everything prepared (and stored up?), then as long as $page_title has been defined *somewhere*, when the page is finally served, it would print the correct result. Is that even possible?! Is that output buffering?

Comment: @Lars It was more meant as a throwaway comment. Output buffering just allows you to store what has been output (i.e. things that have been printed or the like which will get sent to the browser) and get the contents. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php Note I'm not recommending this however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reorder your code to achieve this:

```
<?php 
$requested_page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ($requested_page in $whitelist){
    $page_title = $requested_page;
    include("header.html");
    include ($requested_page . "_controller.php");
    include ($requested_page . "_template.html");
}else{
    //Make sure we include header if page not in white list
    include("header.html");
}

include ("footer.html")
?>
```

Edit: Actually thinking about it you could probably decouple the logic and the includes:

```
<?php 
$requested_page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$includes = array();
$includes[] = 'header.html';
if ($requested_page in $whitelist){
    $page_title = $requested_page;
    $includes[] = $requested_page . "_controller.php";
    $includes[] = $requested_page . "_template.html";
}

$includes[] = "footer.html";
foreach($includes as $include){
    include($include);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this and it does indeed work, but I've just made a quick clarification to my question. The thing I don't like is that in this answer include(header.html) has to be repeated. I want to believe there's a way of doing it by keeping the header and/or footer out of the logic completely!

Comment: @Lars I've added an alternative method which removes duplicating the includes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the second one is a really nice idea

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this for my load MVC library to load views, but I think this will become handy:

```
$target = "myfile.php";

$data = array(
  'page_title' => 'page title'
);

ob_start();
if(count($data) > 0) extract($data);
include_once($target);
$content = ob_get_clean();

echo $content;
```

And you're able to use `$data` keys as variables with use of `extract()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Easy

```
<?php 
$requested_page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$page_title = "";

if ($requested_page in $whitelist) $page_title = $requested_page;

include("header.html");

if(!empty($page_title)) {
    include ($requested_page . "_controller.php");
    include ($requested_page . "_template.html");
}

include ("footer.html")
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about..?

```
<?php 
$page_title = $requested_page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (!in_array($requested_page, $whitelist)) {
    header('Location: http://example.com/your404');
    exit(0);
}

include 'header.html';
include "$requested_page_controller.php";
include "$requested_page_template.html";
include 'footer.html';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try redirecting back to your `index.php` page with a `$_POST` or `$_GET`, with the page title.

If these are set, you can read them from the start of the page.

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['pagetitle'])){
  echo "<html><head><title>".$_GET['pagetitle']."</title></head>";
}

include("header.html");

$requested_page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ($requested_page in $whitelist){
    $page_title = $requested_page;
    include ($requested_page . "_controller.php");
    include ($requested_page . "_template.html");
    header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/index.php?pagetitle='.
           urlencode('This is the page title'),'"' ) 
}

include ("footer.html")

?>
```